# Renaming worksheets in Excel via export from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2008

I' m developing reports from Visual Studio 2010 using .rdlc extension.

There is a requirement where I have to export all reports to one excel file in the form of tabs.

When I export reports to Excel I can see the reports in the form of tabs(sheet1, sheet2, ........).

I want to rename these sheets. I have seen that in SQL Server 2008 R2 there is a property PageName which I' m unable to find in Visual Studio 2010. Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you willing to run a VBA to rename the tabs? or do you want to do renaming in the `R2`?

Comment: Am willing to run a dba. Does it involve calling the GetVstoObject ?

Comment: How can i do the renaming in R2 ? Now am curious

Answer (score 3):

You can try this out:

> **PageName**
>
> Set this and then on export to excel the tab will use the page name.
> This can be set on certain objects in the report and can use Expressions to set the name.
> Objects that contain this property include:

```
 - Tablix
 - Rectangle
```

Here is the tutorial for you to explore:

- [Export reports to Excel with page names set](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s146/pagename-reports.htm)

Comment: The rectangle object doesnt seem to have the PageName property under General. All i have is the Name property and the PageBreak property which are of not much help.

Comment: Can you see tablix? have you looked at the tutorial? Check if the `Target Server Version property` for your project. PageName is only avaialbe in SQL2008R2. So, you won't see it if the target server version is set to `SQL2008` or prior versions...

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. But i don't see the tablix.

Comment: Did you check what I mentioned in the comment? Target server? Please check all and comment.

Comment: Cant find the Target Server Version in visual studio. Checking under my project properties only gives me TargetDataSourceFolder, TargetReportFolder and TargetServerURL.