# Exporting rdlc report in excel and rename the excel sheet in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf

I am developing some reports in Visual Studio 2010 using .rdlc extension.
There is a requirement: I have to export all reports to one excel file in the form of tabs.
When I export the reports to Excel I can see the reports in the form of tabs (sheet1, sheet2, ........).

I want to rename these sheets.

Comment: This question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545677/renaming-worksheets-in-excel-via-export-from-visual-studio-2010